# API call with Curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I need to call this command using curl.

`http -a $CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET --form POST https://api-sandbox.com/auth/token grant_type=client_credentials scope=access_token_only`

I have tried following, but not getting through

```
    $URL = "https://api-sandbox.com/auth/token";


    $data = array(
        'grant_type' => "client_credentials",
        'scope' => "access_token_only"
    );

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_APPEND, "$CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting following error

`{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}`

How can I do it?

Thx

----------------Additional Information -----------------

oAuth2.0 is being used for authentication

Comment: I guess you forgot about `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: What are `scope=access_token_only` things? Are they GET params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked in a following way:

```
$content = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=access_token_only&client_id=".$client_id."&client_secret=".$client_secret;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-sandbox.com/auth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you

```
<?php
$URL = "https://api-sandbox.com/auth/token";

$data = [
    'grant_type' => "client_credentials",
    'scope'      => "access_token_only",
];

$client_id = getenv('CLIENT_ID');
$client_secret = getenv('CLIENT_SECRET');

try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Check if initialization had gone wrong*
    if ( $ch === false ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( 'failed to initialize' );
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-sandbox.com/auth/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=access_token_only");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id . ':' . $client_secret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    if ( $content === false ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( curl_error( $ch ), curl_errno( $ch ) );
    }

    /* Process $content here */

    // Close curl handle
    curl_close( $ch );
} catch ( RuntimeException $e ) {

    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(),
            $e->getMessage()
        ),
        E_USER_ERROR
    );

}
```

Comment: @rgoyal I've updated code. Could you check again?

Comment: @ Urmat: We should not use CURLOPT_USERPWD as client_id and client_secret are not username and password

Comment: `http -a $CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET` from your request mean add authorization

Comment: That's true... we need to add authorization using available parameters... and username, password are not among the available parameters